# Rotation of a system of two masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotation

A uniform disc of mass M and radius R is suspended vertically by a pivot at its periphery. A particle of mass M is fixed to the rim and raised to the highest point above its center. The system is released from rest and can rotate freely about the pivot. The angular velocity of the system when the attached object is directly below the pivot is?

[image]

My attempt at a solution:
The system will rotate about the center of the disc. So the moment of inertia of the system about the center should be 0.5MR+MR<sup>2</sup>=1.5MR<sup>2</sup>/2. Now by energy conservation 0.5IW<sup>2</sup>=2MgR, when the particle reaches it lowest point, considering the top of the disc as a datum. Which gives us $$\sqrt\frac {8gR}{3}$$. However the answer provided is $$\sqrt\frac {24gR}{11}$$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You could consider including a diagram of your setup

Comment: Physics.SE is *not* a homework help site, please see [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are not right:
The moment of inertia about the pivot comes from the the mass at the top and by shifting the centre:

$\frac{1}{2}MR^2+MR^2+M(2R)^2=\frac{11}{2}MR^2$

Now Apply the conservation of energy

$\frac{1}{2}Iw^2=mg(2R+4R)$

Comment: But isn't the axis of rotation of the disc it's centre itself? Why use the parallel axes Theorem then? And also could you explain how you got 4R*Mg?

Comment: As per your diagram the disk rotates about the pivot. So that becomes the centre, Hence the parallel axis theorem, the 4R is the vertical distance travelled by the particle at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Since the disk is pivoting around a point on its circumference (not its centre) you need to use the moment of inertia of the disk about that point, and it's not $1/2MR^2$.